# AD site replication issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, replication

We currently have two sites.  It appears that only one DC is being used to do replication between the sites.  Is this normal?  I would expect this if we had a bridgehead server set up, but we do not.  I expected a link to be created between each server in site A to each server in site B, instead of just one.

All but one connection has been automatically created in our sites.  The one that was not automatically created is between two DCs within one site.  I don't see how that would affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

> We currently have two sites. It appears that only one DC is being used
>   to do replication between the sites. Is this normal?

Yes, it is normal. The ISTG creates a least cost, loop free replication topology between sites. If there were connections between every DC and every other DC between sites you would in fact have a replication loop.

One DC in each site is automatically selected as the bridgehead server for that site and manages replication between it's site and other sites (dependent upon your site link configuration). If the selected bridgehead server becomes unavailable then another DC in that site is selected as the bridgehead server for that site. If you manually select a bridgehead server and that bridgehead server becomes unavailable then replication between that site and other sites will cease.

As for the manually created replication links, you're better off letting the KCC and ISTG create them. You and I are not smarter than the KCC/ISTG. Let them do the job they were intended to do. You can safely delete the manually created connection and the KCC (intra site) or ISTG (inter site) will create them as needed, within about 15 minutes.

Comment: Also, rather than deleting manually created connections and potentially breaking replication until KCC/ISTG regenerates them, you can just set their `options` attribute to a value of 1. This turns the connection into a "generated" connection that will be automatically cleaned up if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I don't usually worry about the "break" in replication because the KCC and ISTG will recreate connections within about 15 minutes, but your suggestion takes a more cautious approach that would be well heeded.